# Google Map not working after adding API showing grey box

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

Google map is showing grey box or sometimes show nothing/white 
i googled some links and try their ways but didn't work for me.
Any solution?
i tried to change the zoom but still not working 
Console shows no error

```
<head>    
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3&amp;hl=en&amp;key=GOOGLE_GENERATED_API&amp;sensor=true"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    function myMap() {
      var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(31.4856,74.3406);
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
      var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 8};
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
      marker.setMap(map);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Welcome to Ali Institute of Education"
      });
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
    </script>



    </head>

    <body onload="myMap()">

    <?php include '/layout/header.php';?>

     <!-- Contact Us Content -->
     <div class="container-fluid">



      <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; overflow:visible;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Perhaps you've exceed the maximum daily load map limits: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/usage-limits?hl=es-419 or just

Comment: @JordiFlores nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&hl=en&key=GOOGLE_GENERATED_API&sensor=true" ></script>

                       <!--OR-->

<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?file=api&amp;v=3&amp;hl=en&amp;key=GOOGLE_GENERATED_API&amp;sensor=true"></script>
```

On this link replace text **GOOGLE_GENERATED_API** with your **google api key**.

Showing perfect on my side. Which error you get on your browser consollog ?
your maps API cdn is not correct. Maybe you get this error **google is not define.** 
google.maps.event.addDomListener (myMap); ADD this line or you can remove the onload from body and add this
google.maps.event.addDomListener (window, 'load', myMap);

Additionaly I have added a click function on marker. If you have any question ask me in comment.

```js
 
     function myMap() {
      var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(31.4856,74.3406);
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
      var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 8};
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
      marker.setMap(map);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Welcome to Ali Institute of Education"
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
  
    google.maps.event.addDomListener (myMap);
//google.maps.event.addDomListener (window, 'load', myMap);
// if you use the window load myMap You don't need onload function on body tag
   }
```

```css
#map{
width: 800px; 
height: 400px; 
overflow:visible;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myMap()">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
  </head>
```

Comment: now i'm getting this error: You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
common.js:48 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys

Comment: i've added the script of api key. i don't know why No Api keys error

Comment: @MuhammadSaadBhatti which error ?? check the API cdn 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&hl=en&key=API_KEY"

Replace The API_KEY with your's

Comment: i mistakenly added 2 times of api key
now this error shows
setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
Uncaught TypeError: marker.setMap is not a function

Comment: Change the script cdn you added. I get same error if I use your script cdn. Check the updated ans for the script cdn